# bzw. einem Gefühl erfüllt

Tags: preposition, conjunction

The following is a definition of "voller" from the Cambridge Dictionary. I'm wondering whether the connection of "einem Gefühl erfüllt " to "mit Dingen oder Personen gefüllt oder bedeckt" via "bzw." is okay. Shouldn't "einem Gefühl erfüllt " have its own preposition? It's obvious that the omitted preposition is "mit." Do natives think the omission is grammatical?

> mit Dingen oder Personen gefüllt oder bedeckt bzw. einem Gefühl erfüllt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot say too much on whether this is correct, but as a native speaker, it sounds weird to me. I would have definitely added another “mit” after “bzw.”

Comment: If answering a question try to find sources supporting the answer you give. It would lend more weight to your argument. Anyway, welcome to German.SE

Answer (score 3):

Actually I consider **von** as the most appropriate preposition for *Gefühl erfüllt*, since there is most likely more specification needed to the kind/origin of the mentioned feeling. (This is different from an inanimate object object, like a jar, which can perfectly filled **with** something.)

Since then the preposition is different from the *mit* at the beginning, there is even less reason to omit it.

---

Update: Other combinations of *erfüllt* are more frequetly used with *mit*, as: *mit Freude/Stolz/Genugtuung erfüllt*.

Comment: FYI, the problematic definition comes from none other than the prestigious Cambridge University Press.

Answer (score 1):

The definition is just excessively shortened, and "einem Gefühl erfüllt" is still meant to belong to the preposition "mit" from the beginning of the definition.

They can shorten it like that if they assume that the reader kowns the language and can cope with the references. "Bzw." can be used as a conjunction exactly like "oder". So yes, it's grammatical.

Other examples for reuse of a preposition in that manner below. You can call it an ellipis if that fits your grammar approach better. I agree with @Artemis' answer that it is uncommon, but it's possible if you are really keen on avoiding repetition.

> Alexander war mit Talent gesegnet und einem reichen Erbe beschenkt.
> Man kann das Fleisch im Ofen garen oder der Pfanne anbraten.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146501/discussion-on-answer-by-halvarf-bzw-einem-gefuhl-erfullt); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.